# How to use Google Cloud Bucket with React Native?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-storage

I have stored my images in Google Cloud Bucket by encrypting it with Google provided key.

I want to decrypt and load on screen the stored image when I get the GCP stored image URL from backend response.

Comment: You can follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/upload-images-to-google-cloud-storage-with-react-native-and-expressjs-61b8874abc49) , as it's a complete tutorial to Upload Images to Google Cloud Storage with React Native and ExpressJS.

Answer (score 2):

To upload images to Google Cloud Storage with React Native, you can follow the next steps:

- First, you need a [Google Service Account Keyfile](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys), download the keyfile in format JSON and save it in your project's directory.
- Next, you've to accept the image via Image Picker/Form, or any other file selector in your code.
- Create a FormData() Object in your code.
- Make a POST request to your App's endpoint as multipart/form-data
- Install [Multer library](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)
- Use Multer library as middelware to parse the request and add a file property to the request object.
- Middleware service to 1) Authenticate with the Google API, 2) define the storage bucket, 3) specify the file name, 4) Upload the image, and 5) send the response
- Pass the above service as middleware to your route, upload the file and return the final Image URL.
- The previous  URL can be accessed directly in the browser, serving up the image publicly for use within your application.

[Here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/upload-images-to-google-cloud-storage-with-react-native-and-expressjs-61b8874abc49) is a complete tutorial with code and each previous step detailed.